# Почему preg_match_all() возвращает не все найденные строки?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$matchesLines = [];

$subject = 'Title: Blazing Saddles
Release Year: 1974
Format: VHS
Stars: Mel Brooks, Clevon Little, Harvey Korman, Gene Wilder, Slim Pickens, Madeline Kahn

Title: Casablanca
Release Year: 1942
Format: DVD
Stars: Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergman, Claude Rains, Peter Lorre

Title: Charade
Release Year: 1953
Format: DVD
Stars: Audrey Hepburn, Cary Grant, Walter Matthau, James Coburn, George Kennedy
';

 if (preg_match_all("/^(Title|Release Year|Format|Stars): *(.*)/",
     $subject,$matchesLines))
 {
     var_dump($matchesLines);
 }
```

Результат вывода `var_dump(matchesLines);`

```
  array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Title: Blazing Saddles (length=23)
  1 => string 'Title' (length=5)
  2 => string 'Blazing Saddles (length=16)
```

Собственно как сделать так что бы `preg_match_all()` возвращал все найденные строки?
[Аналогичный код в онлайн редакторе регулярных выражений для пхп работает корректно](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/psx)

Comment: Я же [написал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52629798/3832970) - *`^` - start of a line (if the multiline mode is enabled)* - трудно было меня спросить? В следующий раз всегда указывайте язык программирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такую регулярку пользуйте:

```
"/^(Title|Release\sYear|Format|Stars):\s*(.*)/m"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629710/how-to-write-a-parsing-template-to-the-end-of-the-line/52629798#52629798

Comment: Это то же самое выражение, просто добавлен модификатор `m` . `\s` потенциально опасен, так как может найти переход на новую строку, лучше использовать `\h*`.

Comment: Почти тоже =) пробелы не всегда правильно работают(от конфига зависит) если записаны пробелом, плюс модификатор именно то чего нехватало в регулярке =)

Comment: Я обновил комментарий.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew мне кажется вы путаете \s и \S, первый означает именно пробельный символ, и не может найти перенос строки, второй - не означает пробельных символов и реагирует на перенос строки

Comment: Я ничего не путаю, я [автор этого регулярного выражения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52629798/3832970).

Comment: тем не менее, **\s** не реагирует на перенос строки, перенос строки это **\S**, кто бы ни был автором этой регулярки это не отменяет поведения метасимволов., добавил в ответ ссылку на оригинальное сообщение(т.е. ваше).

Comment: [Вот что будет](https://regex101.com/r/BGp3ho/1), если вдруг не будет хотя бы одного из значений. При [использовании `\h`](https://regex101.com/r/BGp3ho/2) такого не произойдёт.

Comment: Забавно, значит документации можно не верить слепо. ибо это именно из документации. Можно сслыку на описание \h ?

Comment: См. [Экранирующие последовательности](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Comment: т.е. я правильно понимаю что **\s+** может поймать только **\r** но не **\n** ?

Comment: Неправильно. *`\s` любой пробельный символ*

Comment: разве \n (он же LF он же 0x0A) тоже пробельный символ?